# How can I create this select list from a JSON object using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Yeah, I have 3 or 4 different answers on the same subject but I'm struggling to combine them to create what I need. I serialize my results using Json.Net which results in the following object:

```
"[  { "Id": 1, "OrderInList": 1  },
    { "Id": 2, "OrderInList": 2  },
    { "Id": 4, "OrderInList": 3  }
]"
```

I'd like the option value *and* text to be the OrderInList value (I'll use the Id with something else later).

I've currently got the following code, but it creates *143* option boxes. I can see why it's doing it, but I'm not sure how to alter it to get it to work.

```
    $.getJSON("/Json/GetOrderSelectList?parentCategoryId=" + postData, null, function (jsonResult) {
        $('#orderInList').attr('enabled', 'true');
        $.each(jsonResult, function() {
            $.each(this, function(index, item) {
                                $('#orderInList').append(
                                    $("<option></option>")
                                        .text(index)
                                        .val(index)
                                );

            });
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're trying something like this:

```
var jsonResult = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "OrderInList": 1},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "OrderInList": 2},
{
    "Id": 4,
    "OrderInList": 3}
]

$('#orderInList').attr('enabled', 'true');
$.each(jsonResult, function() {
   $('#orderInList').append(
        $("<option></option>").text(this.Id).val(this.OrderInList);
   );
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vC3u/2/)**

***Full code***

```
$.getJSON("/Json/GetOrderSelectList?parentCategoryId=" + postData, function(jsonResult) {
    $('#orderInList').attr('enabled', 'true');
    $.each(jsonResult, function() {
        $('#orderInList').append(
            $("<option></option>").text(this.Id).val(this.OrderInList)
        );
    });
});​
```

Comment: Excellent. +1 for jsfiddle, looks like a really handy website for this type of stuff. Thanks loads.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the extra call to .each that is nested within the first call to .each.  Just pass the items and the index in the first .each call then create your element.
Try this:

```
var json = [  { "Id": 1, "OrderInList": 1  },
    { "Id": 2, "OrderInList": 2  },
    { "Id": 4, "OrderInList": 3  }
];

function createSelect(options){
    $.each(options,function(index,item){
           $("#orderInList").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.OrderInList).text(item.OrderInList));

    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
createSelect(json);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BzC9N/